# Corona SDK get OpenGL context from native code

Tags: opengl-es, coronasdk, native

Is there a way to get OpenGL context from native code? Lets say, I need to draw something from my obj-c code. Anything, some object, complex bezier curve etc. I know that I need enterprise account. So I'm asking just about the OpenGL context. How it will look like and how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Corona Enterprise has APIs that allow you to interact with the Corona "Environment" from the native code. But I don't think it is possible to add something inside the Corona OpenGL (i.e, possible may even be, but Corona doesn't make that easy for you).

Usually when you draw or add something from the native code, like an image, you add that image to overlay view that is above the Corona OpenGL view. (In fact, that is why when using Corona Pro, all native objects always appear above of your corona elements)